# Selenium does not close browser window with log

Tags: selenium-webdriver

When I run test in Selenium 2, I end with `selenium.close();        selenium.stop();`. In previous version it closed both the windows with tested application and **window with test log**. In Selenium 2 the second window **stays opened** - what I can do to close it too ?

Selenium **2.0a6**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug that made the .close() method fails. Try .quit() instead.

Comment: I already realised that quit() works fro WebDriver in Selenium 2. I hope the same applies to Selenium.